# Sparsest cuts of planar graphs

Tags: algorithms, graphs, optimization, minimum-cuts, planar-graphs

Several algorithms for [sparsest cut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_(graph_theory)#Sparsest_cut) (and other kinds of balanced cuts) in [planar graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph) have been published, like for instance:

- [Finding minimum-quotient cuts in planar graphs](https://doi.org/10.1145/167088.167284), James K. Park, Cynthia A. Phillips, 1993
- [Sparsest cut in planar graphs, maximum concurrent flows and their connections with the max-cut problem](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10107-017-1227-3), Mourad Baïou, Francisco Barahona, 2018
- [A quasipolynomial (2 + ε)-approximation for planar sparsest cut](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3406325.3451103), Vincent Cohen-Addad, Anupam Gupta, Philip N. Klein, Jason Li, 2021

But **I fail to find any implementation**, including in graph cut libraries like [KaHiP](https://kahip.github.io/).

Does anyone have such an implementation, or explanations of why there is none?

Comment: Implementing stuff does not get one tenure.